# Android- How can i selected items from multiple gridViews?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am making an application about clothes. I made the part taking a picture of the cloth and save it to database.

Now i want to get together pieces from the database to create outfits. I am showing the clothes in one layout using different gridView for each category (Shirts , Trousers e.t.c). The number of the gridViews is 6.

How can i select for an example a shirt from the first gridView then a trouser from the second gridView and show them in another activity in ImageViews?

Everything i looked wasn't help me.

Every answer will be useful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create an OnclickListener for the GridView items in your adapter. When the user clicks an item in the gridview, save the value or id of the item. You can retrieve these if you assign the value to the view using setTag(); Then once the user selects an item from each gridview and you have all the values saved, say in an Outfit object, pass the object in a bundle to the next activity.

Comment: Do you have any example in your mind? I got it want you mean but an example would be useful! Thank you!

Comment: I don't but this tutorial site will have all the different aspects such as Gridview, setTag and the onitemclicked Listeners or Onclick listeners you need. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html.

Comment: Is there any other way to help me more?

Answer (score 0):

Tell to the GridView you want to support selecting items:

```
gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```